# Read/write a big file randomly - mmap on every read/write?

Tags: linux, kernel, mmap

Let's say I have a big file , 1Go. I want to *READ* 10ko at offset 10, then *WRITE* 645ko at offset 235689, then *READ* 150Mo at offset 648975,  and so on...

What is the best approach between these two:

- Opening the file and mmap-ing it (which size?). Then do the reads/writes. At the end unmap and close it.
- Or opening the file. On reads/writes, mmap-ing the file (which size?) and then unmamap-ing them. At the end close the file.

Answer (score 1):

Doing mmap(1) on every I/O doesn't sound like the right thing - It would confuse the code reader and possibly the kernel's optimizations, and has no benefit.

You can use pread(1)/pwrite(1) or preadv(1)/pwritev(1) if you want to be explicit about your reads and writes.

If not, you can mmap(1) the entire file (but be sure to use the right flags, probably `MAP_SHARED`) - Linux won't try to load the entire file to memory anyway.